# Injecting Mouse Events in GTK (WebKitWebView)

Tags: linux, events, webkit, gtk

I have a GTK window containing a WebKitWebView that shows a user interface. I receive touch information over USB from a touch panel.

How do I inject mouse down, dragged and up events into the web kit view, without having to move the actual mouse pointer (as there may be multiple touch screens connected to one machine that all need to function independently)?

Comment: I would say these screens should be made into separate displays anyway (if you need e.g. screen saver firing up separately, or perhaps want to add a keyboard). You may assign each display its own mouse and keyboard so there's no problem moving the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an appropriate GDK Event (GdkEventButton for mouse button events) and put it in the event queue using

```
void gdk_event_put(const GdkEvent *event)
```

See the GDK documentation for details.